# Parse get JsonObject with Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Trying to get the values from the row inside of the object as the photo shows.but i'am having some troubles getting.[this is my json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o2fq.png)

Iam trying to get some rows like "location" or "content"

```
 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                        String value = jsonObject.getString("location");
                        Log.d("test", value);

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    JSONObject photo;

    {
        try {
            photo = response.getJSONObject("photo");
            JSONObject owner = photo.getJSONObject("owner");
            JSONObject title = photo.getJSONObject("title");

            String _content = title.getString("_content");
            String location = owner.getString("location");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also check this blog on how to parse json [Parsing Vollery Json Response](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-fetch-json/)

Comment: @vpedro72 If it solved your question, don't forget to accept the answer.